# Regular expression: searching an arbitrary file for MD5

Tags: regex, md5

See the following ASCII string of 34 characters. I'm trying to have 3 matches of MD5 hash on this string.

> 8AC905DD4AB2038E5F7EABEAE792AC41BC

`[A-F0-9]{32}` matches only the first 32 characters.

This is part of binary reverse engineering project I have.

How I can get 3 different matches from the mentioned string? Any idea is appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: What language/regex engine are you using?

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm not sure what you mean by "I'm trying to have 3 matches of MD5 hash on this string". Is the problem that you're only matching the first 32 characters? If so, the {32} part of your regex is what's restricting the match to that length.

Comment: I use boost regex library, which is compatible with PCRE I guess. [A-F0-9]{32} will get me only one match on the first 32 characters (8AC905DD4AB2038E5F7EABEAE792AC41). But I need the second match (AC905DD4AB2038E5F7EABEAE792AC41B) and the third match (C905DD4AB2038E5F7EABEAE792AC41BC) as well, which doesn't happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not say what language do you use, thus I provided two snippets - for Python and for PHP. But the clue here is the `(?=([A-F0-9]{32}))` pattern (see examples below).

### Solution (Python)

There is a solution, and the following is written in Python:

```
>>> import re 
>>> data = '8AC905DD4AB2038E5F7EABEAE792AC41BC'
>>> matches = re.finditer(r'(?=([A-F0-9]{32}))', data)
>>> results = [match.group(1) for match in matches]
```

### Test

The result will be (as in [this demo](http://ideone.com/1VA9F)):

```
>>> results
['8AC905DD4AB2038E5F7EABEAE792AC41', 'AC905DD4AB2038E5F7EABEAE792AC41B', 'C905DD4AB2038E5F7EABEAE792AC41BC']
```

which is what you have been expecting.

### Solution (PHP)

In PHP it could look like this:

```
<?php

$data = '8AC905DD4AB2038E5F7EABEAE792AC41BC';
$results = array();
preg_match_all('/(?=([A-F0-9]{32}))/', $data, $results);
```

and the `$results` would be the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8AC905DD4AB2038E5F7EABEAE792AC41
    [1] => AC905DD4AB2038E5F7EABEAE792AC41B
    [2] => C905DD4AB2038E5F7EABEAE792AC41BC
)
```

See [this demo](http://ideone.com/MHKj5) for a proof.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This answers my question. As you demonstrated, positive lookahead is the only way to capture 3 matches using regex. Cheers,

Comment: @patrafter: Thanks, I am glad I was able to help. Good luck!